# Importing Specific python modules

Tags: python, python-module

Suppose I have a file file1.py as follows :

```
class a(object):
    **body**

class b(object):
    **body
```

And I have another file file2.py as

```
from file1 import a
```

If There is a syntax error in b, why does it throw an error if I am only importing a ??

Answer (score 0):

The module (that is: the file) is loaded all at once, not selectively, because to load a specific function/class/..., the interpreter needs to parse the entire file, so *syntax* errors will make the import fail, as will any error that occurs if the file was executed.

What will not make the import fail if for instance in `b` you had a function that divides by zero or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you import the file compiler reads the file which is being imported and if there is any error in the file being imported compiler will catch it. 
You you need to make sure that there is no error in module which you're trying to import...